# Async.parallelLimit Function Executing Callback Function Before Tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, async.js, postman-newman

I am attempting to setup some newman test runs in parallel for different environments, and then create a Jira ticket via API request once all are completed with the results.  However, when I use the `ansync.parallelLimit` function for that task, I find that the jira ticket gets created without any of the information from the test runs.

A simplified version of the process is this:

```
var async = require('async');
const path = require('path');
const newman = require('newman');
config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.json'));

const jira_data = [];

var create_ticket = function(err, results){
    console.log("Run Complete");
};

var test_run = async() =>{
  newman.run({
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'Test.postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: ['htmlextra'],
    reporter: {
      htmlextra : { export : path.join(__dirname, '/reports/Test.html')}
    },})
}

var commands = [test_run,test_run,test_run,test_run];

async.parallelLimit(commands,4, (err, results) => {
  console.log("Run Complete");
  console.log(results);
});
```

That will result in the following output, indicating create_ticket was executed before anything else:

> Run Complete
> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Created the htmlextra report.
> Created the htmlextra report.
> Created the htmlextra report.
> Created the htmlextra report.

Alternatively, I can make test_run a function instead of async, like this:

```
var async = require('async');
const path = require('path');
const newman = require('newman');

const jira_data = [];

var create_ticket = function(err, results){
    console.log("Test Run Complete");
};

var test_run = function() {
  newman.run({
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'Test.postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: ['htmlextra'],
    reporter: {
      htmlextra : { export : path.join(__dirname, '/reports/Test.html')}
    },}).on('request', function(err, results) {
      console.log("Hello");
    })
}

var commands = [test_run, test_run, test_run, test_run];

async.parallelLimit(commands, 4, create_ticket);
```

But now, create ticket doesn't run at all:

> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Using htmlextra version 1.22.3
> Hello
> Hello
> Hello
> Hello
> Created the htmlextra report.
> Created the htmlextra report.
> Created the htmlextra report.
> Created the htmlextra report.

After spending more time than I care to admit playing with different combinations of variable types, argument passing, and other fixes, I am completely stumped.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass and call a callback into test_run to complete the asynchronous task.

```js
var test_run = function(callback) {
  newman.run({
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'Test.postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: ['htmlextra'],
    reporter: {
      htmlextra : { export : path.join(__dirname, '/reports/Test.html')}
    },}).on('request', function(err, results) {
      console.log("Hello");
      callback(null);
    })
}
```